# Out sync sound and picture between two players

Tags: ios, swift, libvlc, audiokit

I am building a karaoke app with the ability to sing with video so here is my problem:
I am recording the user video (video only from the front camera)  along with applying voice filters with audiokit on a separate audio records.
Now in my playback, i want to play the video and the audio in a sync mode but it didn't succeed because a have an out sync of video and audio.
I am using akplayer for audio so i can apply voice mod and vlckit for playing user video.

```
         do {

        //MARK: VLC kit part of the video setup
        Vlc_VideoPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

        Vlc_VideoPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: recordVideoURL)
        Vlc_VideoPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "time", options: [], context: nil)
        Vlc_VideoPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "remainingTime", options: [], context: nil)

        Vlc_VideoPlayer.drawable = self.CameraView

        //MARK: Audiokit with AKPlayer Setup

        file = try AKAudioFile(forReading: recordVoiceURL)
        player =  AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
        self.player.preroll()
        delay = AKVariableDelay(player)
        delay.rampTime = 0.5
        delayMixer = AKDryWetMixer(player, delay)

        reverb = AKCostelloReverb(delayMixer)
        reverbMixer = AKDryWetMixer(delayMixer, reverb)
        booster = AKBooster(reverbMixer)
        tracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(booster)
        AudioKit.output = tracker
        try AudioKit.start()
        }catch{
        print (error)
              }
        self.startPlayers()
```

now the startPlayers function :

```
func startPlayers(){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {


                self.Vlc_VideoPlayer.audio.isMuted = true
                self.Vlc_VideoPlayer.play()



            self.player.isLooping = false
            self.player.play()




        }else{
            self.startPlayers()
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the VLC player, but with the built in AVPlayer there is an option to sync to a clock:

```
var time: TimeInterval = 1 // 1 second in the future

videoPlayer.masterClock = CMClockGetHostTimeClock()

let hostTime = mach_absolute_time()

let cmHostTime = CMClockMakeHostTimeFromSystemUnits(hostTime)
let cmVTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, preferredTimescale: videoPlayer.currentTime().timescale)
let futureTime = CMTimeAdd(cmHostTime, cmVTime)
videoPlayer.setRate(1, time: CMTime.invalid, atHostTime: futureTime)
```

AKPlayer then supports syncing to the mach_absolute_time() hostTime using its scheduling functions. As you have above, the two will start close together but there is no guarantee of any sync.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to start two players will work out of pure look and unless you have means to synchronize playback after it started, it will not be perfect. Ideally, you should play the audio with VLC as well to make use of its internal synchronization tools.

To iterate on what you have right now, I would suggest to start playback with VLC until it decoded the first frame, pause, start your audio and continue playback with VLC as soon as you decoded the first audio sample. This will still not be perfect, but probably better.